# Get name of Tool Strip Menu Item into messagebox

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

I have a Tool Strip Menu with an entry named "General". When the form is loaded sub items are added to the "General" entry which are the result of reading the file names of text files in a folder.

I want to be able to capture the names of the sub items and add them to a label in the generic form which is called from clicking on the sub item.

I've tried using `MsgBox(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Text)` in an attempt to capture the text initially, however, it just gives me the "General" menu item in the messagebox

I am currently using this code in the `DropDownItemClicked` event

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submenu items are in the collection ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems. You can cycle through the collection and select the ToolStripMenuItems. Not every item in the menu is a ToolStripMenuItem (there are separators, buttons, etc.), so you can cycle through with a ToolStripItem.

This example puts all the submenu items in a message box:

```
Private Sub mnuDraw_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuDraw.Click

Dim s As String = ""
For Each item As ToolStripItem In sender.DropDownItems
  If TypeOf (item) Is ToolStripMenuItem Then s &= item.Text & vbCrLf
  Next item
MsgBox(s)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, probably being a bit dumb but I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: It's not dumb if you don't have all the information... I'll explain a little better.

Comment: I get it now, thanks - just need to adapt it so it only displays the selected menu item